# Can this design be considered as a banner?

Tags: logo

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers, they're all pertinent to the question I've asked.

However, it's not really what I've been expecting, i.e. it's not the right question I've asked !

---

Can you tell whether this entitles to be considered as a banner or not ?

Portion of the banner at 1:1

[image]

Full banner (right-click and open image in new tab on your browser to see it at 1:1 scale)

[image]

**EDIT**

I forgot a detail actually, its usage will be in a desktop application.

[image]

Comment: Well now I don't understand the question. Whats a banner in your app? Do you mean would people assume thats something to click on? Or what exactly is the question now?

Comment: Yes, it would have 2 purposes, to show the brand and to provide access to a few essentials functions. Here's a concrete example from Traktor 2 software : http://images-ec.native-instruments.com/fileadmin/ni_media/dj/traktor_kontrol_f1/images/02_draft_packaging_shots_L.jpg?1328113496

Comment: Define "banner" for us. What is your particular concern?

Comment: Well I don't know in fact ! I called it a banner because its shape reminds me so but that's it. I'm not a graphic designer but a coder in fact and from time to time I need to do some stuff like this. My knowledge and vocabulary is certainly incorrect/incomplete about the subject ... with all the answers posted so far I'm starting to think that it ain't the right question I've been asking.

Comment: What is the concern you have? Do you *want* it to look like a banner? Why or why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking anything can be considered a "banner." The important thing is what dimensions the website you're putting it on requires it to be.

One set of standards is by the [IAB](http://www.iab.net/). In my work the IAB is still a minor player though. Maybe if you're advertising on blogs it plays more of a role on those square ads that always show up on the sidebar but otherwise I don't see IAB having any significant market share.

There is no set requirements for what must be on a banner so if your question is more content driven then yes, it is a banner. Nearly anything can be considered a banner.

**Edit**

Based on your edit I would as Boblet said call this a header or even just the logo. If you intend on having it access a few essential functions I would add some indicator like 3 dots or 3 lines which has become fairly standard, a down arrow might work, anything really to indicate that it has options within it. At that point and depending on how you design it I would probably call it... a menu.

Comment: Good answer! Absolutely follow the IAB sizes guidelines if the goal is to provide images and links which will generate click-throughs on other sites. Not many sites will consider advertising which is non-standard size and requires special consideration in their site layout.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that it was for using it an application, I've updated the question. Do you think you can update your answer accordingly to this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can, as Ryan point out, call it a banner if you like. Seeing the context of the image, I would maybe tend toward calling it heading or header. But there are really no solid definitions here at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define [banner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner) first. In the context that you are asking, you mean advertising banners and in general when we say banner we consider a [web banner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_ad) or any other ads almost always CLICKABLE , including on desktop applications.

As mentioned above there are some standards, but they are not strict. The general size you can see via link provided or here on the picture.

If you ask about **subjective view by the users** - i.e. if they will understand that the header is a LINK and is clickable - I have a little doubt about that - probably if you add some arrow or other sign it will be more suitable. In any way - don't use any flashing ads - users hate them and your app will be downrated.

To sum up, by definition you have a banner, by subjective feeling - probably you should add some expression/object on it to be understandable.

IAB standards

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to give context. For what reason are you trying to define a name for the image? Is it for internal discussion, for writing documentation? No one knows why you are asking this question. The pictures are nice, but there's no context.

I think in your app you can call it anything, as long as you don't call it the file menu or the application shell. Again, no one knows who you're trying to sell the name of that image to, so it honestly doesn't matter. Header, banner, there's no difference until you apply a context to it.